# Reset text field on ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is not resetting the field back to nothing:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#ProblemButton').click(function (event) {
                 var form = $('#Form1');
                 $.ajax({

                     type: form.attr('method'),
                     url: form.attr('action'),
                     data: $("#reportProblem :input").serialize(),
                     cache: false,

                 }).done(function (data) {
                     $('#reportProblem').modal('hide');

                     if (data.ResponseType == 0) {
                         $('#SuccessMsg').text('Problem Reported');
                         $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');

                     }
                     else if (data.ResponseType == 1) {
                         $("#SuccessMsg").attr("class", "alert alert-danger");
                         $('#SuccessMsg').text('Can not report problem');
                         $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                     }

                     else {
                         $('#SuccessMsg').text('Data: ' + data.ResponseType + $("#reportProblem :input").serialize());
                         $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                     }
                     $('#problemDescription').attr('value', '');

                     // Optionally alert the user of success here...


                     setTimeout(function () { $('#SuccessMessage').modal('hide'); }, 3000);


                 }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                     // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                     alert("Error submitting AJAX request" + textStatus);
                 });
                 event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
             });
         });
```

Out of content:

```
       $('#problemDescription').attr('value', '');
```

The HTML element is here:

```
     <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="problemDescription" Columns="80" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Try `$('#problemDescription').val('');`

Comment: Are you sure that line of code is being executed? try debugging it... also, it is probably better to use `$('#problemDescription').val('');`

Comment: Do you get any console errors? I would guess that your `done` function isn't even working (or dying on another line of code). But as you didn't answer the question is my last comment I would also guess you don't have any intention of working the problem out... just waiting for copy/paste answers instead

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct id to reset value? Try like this: `$("[id*='problemDescription']").attr('value', '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing the `ClientIDMode="Static"` becouse the control is ASP.net control and the Id is changing:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="problemDescription" Columns="80" Rows="5" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

With that you can use:

```
$('#problemDescription').val('');
```

Comment: @CorbinSpicer You are pretty sure that the all the code it's executting before cleaning the Textbox?

Comment: I've managed to get it work on click of the problem button rather than when it submits. Thanks